# Calling MFC application from command line with arguments + stdout + stderr

Tags: c++, mfc, command-line-arguments, stdout, stderr

I am trying to call my MFC application with input arguments from command line.

I would like the application to print output to a file and errors to another file.

So in addition to the input arguments, I pass `1>out.txt 2>err.txt`.

Overall, the command line looks something like:

```
start /w app.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 1>out.txt 2>err.txt
```

It did seem to work for a little while, writing results to both files.

However, at some point it stopped, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

**Header File:**

```
class CMyWinApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance();
};
```

**Source File:**

```
CMyWinApp myWinApp;

BOOL CMyWinApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();       
    int iNumOfArgs;
    LPWSTR* pArgs = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(),&iNumOfArgs);
    for (int iArgNum=1; iArgNum<iNumOfArgs; iArgNum++)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"%ls\n",pArgs[iArgNum]);
        fprintf(stderr,"%ls\n",pArgs[iArgNum]);
    }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved:

I added the `start /w` at some point, in order to force waiting for completion.

For some reason, as a result, nothing is written into the two destination files.